# как отсортировать значения в словаре?

Tags: python

Пусть имеется словарь:

```
{'+7': 2345678901, '+4': 3456789012, '+5': 5678901234, '+12': 78901234}
```

Необходимо вывести телефонные номера по убыванию чисел, указанных в ключах, то есть, в порядке:

+4, +5, +7, +12

пробовал использовать функцию `sorted()`, но ничего не получалось

Comment: В самом словаре отсортировать значения нельзя (он же словарь, а не список). А вот вывести отсортированные - это уже другое дело )

Comment: вывести только номера: `[v for _,v in sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: int(x[0]))]` где `d` - ваш словарь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Немного меньше оверхеда, но тож самое, что и у предыдущего оратора:

```py
>>> d={'+7': 2345678901, '+4': 3456789012, '+5': 5678901234, '+12': 78901234}
>>> dict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: int(x[0])))
{'+4': 3456789012, '+5': 5678901234, '+7': 2345678901, '+12': 78901234}
```

Answer (score 2):

Если требуется отсортировать ключи как числа, то в процедуре сортировки надо превратить эти строки в числа.

```
d = {'+7': 2345678901, '+4': 3456789012, '+5': 5678901234, '+12': 78901234}

# сортированный список кортежей
print([(k,v) for k,v in sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: (int(x[0][1:]), x[1]))])

# сортированный новый словарь
print({k:v for k,v in sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: (int(x[0][1:]), x[1]))})
```